# CP Python Logic Confusion on Modern Art (Bronze USACO 2017 US Open p.3)

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, logic

### Problem Info

USACO 2017 US Open Bronze Problem 3 Modern Art [Problem Link](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=737)

### My Work

```py
# Read in grid as 2D array
with open("art.in", 'r') as fin:
    n = int(fin.readline().strip())
    grid = [[int(i) for i in fin.readline().strip()] for _ in range(n)]
print(grid)

# Get all possible colors, which is everything visible excluding zero
possible = set()
for row in grid:
    for p in row:
        possible.add(p)
if 0 in possible:
    possible.remove(0)
print(possible)

# Recursive search function that gets the maximum x of the triangle and maximum y of the triangle, which will be used further down the road to calculate whether or not it is a valid rectangle
def search(grid, i, j, v):
    global max_x, max_y, searched, area
    if i < 0 or i >= n or j < 0 or j >= n or grid[i][j] != v or (i, j) in searched:
        max_x = max(max_x, j)
        max_y = max(max_y, i)
        return
    searched.append((i, j))
    area += 1
    search(grid, i+1, j, v)
    search(grid, i-1, j, v)
    search(grid, i, j+1, v)
    search(grid, i, j-1, v)

# Use the search, and check if there is a possibility of the rectangle being covered. It it is covered, eliminate the rectangle that covers it from the list of possibilities.
searched = []
for i, row in enumerate(grid):
    for j, p in enumerate(row):
        if (i, j) in searched or not p:
            continue
        max_x = 0 
        max_y = 0
        # The area variable is uneeded. Using it for debugging
        area = 0
        search(grid, i, j, p)
        print(area, (max_x-j) * (max_y-i))
        print()

        for k in range(i, max_y):
            for l in range(j, max_x):
                if grid[k][l] != p and grid[k][l] in possible:
                    possible.remove(grid[k][l])

# Write the answer to the output file
with open('art.out', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(str(len(possible)))
```

### Problem

My logic is pretty clear from the code, and I can get 6 out of 10 test cases, but when I try an input like:

```
4
1234
1234
1234
1334
```

My program outputs 4 instead of 3, which is the correct answer. Therein lies my problem. I have no idea why it is 3 and not 4

### What I've Tried

I've read over the problem multiple times, and I still don't get it.

If anyone could help explain it, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my teacher and he gave me this:

```
with open('art.in', 'r') as fin:
    n=int(fin.readline().strip())
    grid=[[int(i) for i in fin.readline().strip()] for _ in range(n)]

rect=[]
for clr in range(10):
    rect.append([n,n,-1,-1])

# Find out rect for each color
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        a=grid[i][j]
        if a>0:
            rect[a][0]=min(rect[a][0],i)
            rect[a][1]=min(rect[a][1],j)
            rect[a][2]=max(rect[a][2],i)
            rect[a][3]=max(rect[a][3],j)

ans=0
not_original=[0]*10
for clr in range(10):
    if rect[clr][0]<n:
        ans=ans+1
        # any color inside another rect cannot be original color
        for i in range(rect[clr][0], rect[clr][2]+1):
            for j in range(rect[clr][1], rect[clr][3]+1):
                if grid[i][j]!=clr:
                    not_original[grid[i][j]]=1

with open("art.out", 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(str(ans-sum(not_original)))
```

The main difference is that I forgot that each rectangle might look like

```
**6
**6
*66
```

and my program didn't take in the bottom middle `6` into account.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an important part of this problem is to identify "broken" rectangles in the input (i.e rectangles that have overlap). In the case of your last example, `1`, `2`, and `4` are "complete" rectangles, in the sense that they are not explicitly overlapped by any other tiles. `3`, however, is clearly overlapped by `2`, thus, either `2` or `3` existed first, not both. Therefore, there are two complete plus one group of incomplete, giving `3` as the final result. Below is code for a possible solution to this problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def w_h(points):
   d = {'w':set(), 'h':set()}
   for a, b in points:
      d['h'].add(a)
      d['w'].add(b)
   return [max(b) - min(b) + 1 for b in d.values()]

def original_paintings(p):
  d = defaultdict(list)
  for x, a in enumerate(p):
     for y, s in enumerate(a):
        if s:
           d[s].append((x, y))
  r = {a:(wh:=w_h(b))[0]*wh[1] - len(b) for a, b in d.items()}
  return len(r) - len(set(r.values())) + 1

t1 = [[2, 2, 3, 0], [2, 7, 3, 7], [2, 7, 7, 7], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
t2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 3, 4]]
print(original_paintings(t1))
print(original_paintings(t2))
```

Output:

```
1
3
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting long after I marked it right. Was busy. Your logic is correct, but your implementation has some errors when faced with a input set with a color that only has an area of one: like `233
112
944` where it returns 4 instead of 3

Comment: @CoderTang Frankly, I don't see how `3` is obtained from that sample. There are five total colors and `2` is the only overlapped rectangle. By the logic of the example problems, `9`, `4`, `1`, and `3` *could* all be standalone rectangles at the beginning, with `2` added later.

Comment: Oh wait. I didn't think that through. That was a custom test case... sorry about that

Comment: I tried to make a smaller version of the test case `00333000
00333777
22333447
28333847
98333847
55333547
55555547
55555547
` where it prints `2` instead of `3`. `5`, `9`, and `7` are all possible outcomes.

Comment: @CoderTang How is `3` produced from that sample?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2, 7, and 9 as valid 1st paints. The program outputs 2 instead of 3